# Type-casting @property for concrete child class

Tags: objective-c

I am designing a abstract base class for a model, where one property of the base class is currently `id`. I'd like the concrete classes to define what this "content" property type is. Is it safe to redefine the property with a specific type for compiler checking?

Base class `.h`:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) id content;
@end
```

Concrete class `.h`:

```
@interface TextFoo : Foo
...
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *content;
@end
```

Concrete class `.m` now requires a `@synthesize` for `NSString *content`. Is this override safe to do, or are there unintended side effects? At some top level controller I will be using introspection for a collection of `Foo`s, so I'm really only looking for compiler checking on concrete classes.

**Edit**: Just to add some additional information, this does actually work (Xcode 5.0.2) with no warnings or errors from the compiler. The abstract base class can even assign an arbitrary object in a setter and the subclass setter/getter still works.

Comment: @godel9 I think it is possible if you are not writing setters/ getters yourself and thereby not writing synthesize

Comment: @EvolGate Right you are... Definitely not what I was expecting.

Comment: @EvolGate Running a test myself, it still works even if the superclass does @synthesize and/or creates a `-(id)` setter.

Comment: Exactly earlier it used to give exception, but nowadays it does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be very honest some (or I should say many) programmers would consider this a poor architecture design. You can do this but should not be doing this.

As far as the "safety" is considered, that is solely your responsibility now with this approach as compiler won't back you up here (thanks to dynamic nature of Objective-C). Your code may become completely safe if you keep in mind that `content` is no more an **`id`** type.

There might arise a situation where you assign `content` of base class to let's say NSDictionary object (which is pretty much valid) and somehow (if you are drunk and coding) you end up assigning this value to child's `content` (again thanks to dynamic nature of Objective-C, its pretty much valid). So now in this case you are not safe and your app might crash somewhere. So the moral of the story is I am not saying No to Drunken Coding, but I am saying no to poor architecture.

Comment: Thanks, got the picture. What would be a good way to let users of my concrete class know that the inherited property should be a specific type? It seems like protocols would have the same limitation as a base class would.

Comment: By users you mean base class right?

Comment: Users meaning any other code calling. If I make an instance of concrete class, can I document or enforce in some way that the `content` property is, say, `NSString`? Or is just commenting the only way to do this?

Comment: If your property is defined NSString, then compiler is there to back you up and you will receive a compile time error. There is no such compile errors with id types only. If you are sticking to your architecture then AFAIK commenting is the only option